# Convert ASP.NET membership passwords from clear text to hashed

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash

We were hashing our passwords, although somewhere along the way one of our developers changed it to clear text so that we could email a user their password if they forgot it.

Anyhow, I'm changing it so that we store passwords 'hashed' now. There is a group of passwords which we need to hash. The salt is already there in the database, I just need to loop through where "passwordformat" = 0 and hash accordingly. How do I do this?

edit: I had a go at a suggestion from another SO post, using "SHA-1" as the hashing algorithm to calculate the digest. It was not the result I expected.

I know the original clear password, the salt, but the result is not what I expected. The answer in the above suggests using SHA-1 as the hashing algo.

If it's any help this is from our web.config of the web server.

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,
```

EDIT: I'm getting somewhere. I created another test user, and this time got the same digest value as that generated by the web application. Only difference was the one salt contained '/' symbol, and the other did not. I was not aware that '/' would cause an issue, as I didn't think it's an escape character.

EDIT: here is my code. It works only if the salt does not contain '/'

```
public static string EncodePassword3(string pass, string saltBase64)
    {

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(saltBase64);
        byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
        byte[] inArray = null;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);

        HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
        inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }
```

I can supply the clear text password and salt (only testing at mo) to see if you can get the correct result....

Comment: which algorithm u need for hashing?

Comment: good question. will have to find out. have written a little program based on the responses here - the digest I calculated is not what it should be though (I know original password, salt and the end result). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798638/convert-asp-net-membership-passwords-from-encrypted-to-hashed?rq=1

Comment: apparently the default for ASP.NET is SHA1

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses
did u use that code on clear text passwords?

Comment: no I used the one I linked to above. Will give that one a go, many thanks.

Comment: Wal - I've had a go at that code, but it's still creating digests that are different from what I'm after. Is it significant that I'm doing this on my development machine instead of the IIS server? e.g. is there another value used by SHA1 which I need to replicate?