# How to hash password using Membership API

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I use the following code to hash passwords:

```
string passw = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPassword.Text, "SHA1");
```

Above works just fine but I get a warning which says:
Warning 103

```
'System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(string, string)' is obsolete: 'The recommended alternative is to use the Membership APIs, such as Membership.CreateUser.
```

So far I have not being able to find the equivalent code using the membership API.

Comment: as a side note => `Membership.CreateUser` would create a user with hashed password and would store it in database.

Comment: his is an enterprise application and user name and passwords are stored in users table in the DB, (not web config file). How you store result of CreateUser method in SQL Server database?

Comment: @S Nash - Yes I know So I mentioned it like as a side note :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not worry about hashing the password. When you use `CreateUser` method it will be already hashed (depending on the configuration in the WebConfig).

```
Membership.CreateUser("username", "password");
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to configure password options, you can do this in Web.Config using `passwordFormat` attribute as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949728/1845408

Here is a good discussion on hashing passwords in C#, hope this helps:

[Hash and salt passwords in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This is an enterprise application and user name and passwords are stored in users table in the DB, (not web config file).
How you store result of CreateUser method in the database?

Comment: The buttom line question is how to store the user name and password(hashed) in the database. I do not need DB code, but I need to have username and password(hashed) before I write them to the DB.

Comment: I got it you mean you are not using asp.net membership authentication, and that is why you need to hash the password, is that right?

Comment: you should check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138429/hash-and-salt-passwords-in-c-sharp