# Loop through membership list and get users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to test my code by getting 10 specific users that was created recently or having a specific character. I have based my code to this one. This code is from Dan.
[Changing passwordFormat from Encrypted to Hashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948824/changing-passwordformat-from-encrypted-to-hashed)

```
void HashAllPasswords()
    {
        var clearProvider = Membership.Providers["SqlProvider_Clear"];
        var hashedProvider = Membership.Providers["SqlProvider_Hashed"];
        int dontCare = 2;
        if (clearProvider == null || hashedProvider == null) return;
                        var passwords = encrypted.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out dontCare)
        .Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsLockedOut == false && u.IsApproved == true).OrderByDescending(u => u.CreationDate).ToDictionary(u => u.UserName, u => u.GetPassword());
    
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(
               ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                   "UPDATE [aspnet_Membership] SET [PasswordFormat]=1", conn))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    var count = 0;
        foreach (var entry in passwords)
        {
            var resetPassword = hashedProvider.ResetPassword(entry.Key, null);
            hashedProvider.ChangePassword(entry.Key, resetPassword, entry.Value);
            count++;
        if (count == 2)
            break;
        }
    }
```

So basically instead of changing all the users I just wanted to change 10 users or maybe 100 depending on the amount that I wanted. Also I am receiving an error in

> var records

it says

The error is

> Item has already been added.  Key in dictionary: 'sample@email.com'
> Key being added: 'sample@email.com'.

Is there a way to resolve this? Maybe I am using linq in the wrong way.

Comment: does it matter which users  or just a number of users.  also does it need to be able to start with a letter(eg i and do that many users)?

Comment: @IsaacMorris its somewhat similar like the "like" in sql. Just want to get the users who have a "test" in their names for example. Or is it possible to get only fix amount of users before I loop them and change passwords. The constraints is basically if if it takes too long and execution timeout happens because it gets all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you have same user name in your database cause `Dictionary` can't has same key so create use `List`. Create a `User` class first and put the data into it.

About too many data to cause the SQL timeout you need to update the SQL query in `GetAllUsers()`

About the SQL `like` you can use `Contains`

About the count you can use `Take()`

```
   public class User
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
```

```
                var passwords = encrypted.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out dontCare)
                    .Cast<MembershipUser>()
                    .Where(u => u.IsLockedOut == false && u.IsApproved == true)
                    .OrderByDescending(u => u.CreationDate)
                    .Select(x => new User
                    {
                        UserName = x.UserName,
                        Password = x.GetPassword()
                    });


                //someting like SQL likie
                passwords.Where(user => user.UserName.Contains("Test")).ToList().ForEach(
                    x =>
                    {
                        //reset passwrod
                    });

                // get count
                passwords.Take(10).ToList().ForEach(
                    x =>
                    {
                        //reset passwrod
                    });
```

Comment: Hello Michaelmao. Thank you for the response. I tried the code above but I am encountering a connection timeout. I have 300k+ of data in my table. I tried putting "connection timeout =  0 or 9000" to extend it but it is still the same. Do you know whats causing this? Is there a way to fix this sir?

Comment: Change the ```encrypted.GetAllUsers``` don't get some many data in one query or increase timeout